# How to move camera along a straight line in Three.js?

Tags: graphics, camera, three.js

I'm just getting started with Three.js and graphical programming in general. All I'm trying to do is smoothly transition a camera from one position to another.

One solution I found utilized PathControls.js, which has since been removed.

Comment: searching for `tween` will probably help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should be of help. Requires tween.js which you can find in the examples/js/libs folder of three.js

```
function setupCameraPositionTween( source, target, duration, delay, easing )
{
    var l_delay = ( delay !== undefined ) ? delay : 0;
    var l_easing = ( easing !== undefined ) ? easing : TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None;

    new TWEEN.Tween( source )
        .to( target, duration )
        .delay( l_delay )
        .easing( l_easing )
        .onUpdate ( function()
            {
                // copy incoming position into camera position
                camera.position.copy( source );
            })
        .start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my immediate problem but now I have a whole new set of problems to deal with. That's just how it goes though, thanks!